# Filter orders only by a month AND/OR year

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've tried to search for a solution but nothing really worked for me.

this is how my database look like:

```
{ 
  _id: 5e17a001f1e0220def7a2b5d,
  timestamp: "2019-12-10T02:16:41.890+00:00",
  products: [1,2,3]
  total: 300
},
{ 
  _id: 5e17a001f1e0220def7a2b5d,
  timestamp: "2019-5-10T02:16:41.890+00:00",
  products: [1,2,3]
  total: 400
},
{ 
  _id: 5e17a001f1e0220def7a2b5d,
  timestamp: "2020-12-10T02:16:41.890+00:00",
  products: [1,2,3]
  total: 300
}
```

I want to get all the items by passing `Month`(1-12) and `Year` value.

For example, requesting me all items from `5` + `2019`, will give me the following:

```
{ 
  _id: 5e17a001f1e0220def7a2b5d,
  timestamp: "2019-5-10T02:16:41.890+00:00",
  products: [1,2,3]
  total: 400
},
```

requesting me all items from `2019`, will give me the following:

```
{ 
  _id: 5e17a001f1e0220def7a2b5d,
  timestamp: "2019-12-10T02:16:41.890+00:00",
  products: [1,2,3]
  total: 300
},
{ 
  _id: 5e17a001f1e0220def7a2b5d,
  timestamp: "2019-5-10T02:16:41.890+00:00",
  products: [1,2,3]
  total: 400
}
```

**Edit**: I made it work somehow but it doesn't work very well when I use another condition.

I want to display all of the orders in my collection as a default. And if the user entered "total = 300", filter those. In addition, user can filter date. So I want to use multiple conditions.

this is the code which worked for me when I only want to filter by 1 condition (date):

```
    Order.find({
      timestamp: {
         '$gte': new Date(2019, 5, 1), '$lt': new Date(2019, 5, 31) 
        }
    })
```

How do I add a condition that if X=true, only then use the "timestamp" condition?

Comment: Do you mean something like total != 300 OR (timestamp in May-2019) ?